# Write migration changes to django simple history

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-simple-history

`django-simple-history` writing history changes on `instance.save()` method. But when I wrote migration which change instance data, the changes did not appear.

Is the `save()` method of

```
Model = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
```

and

```
MyModel
```

are same? Is there a way to write this changes to history?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`django-simple-history` uses a `post_save` signal on `MyModel` in order to save to the historical table. That signal isn't sent in your migrations, so you want to write directly to the historical table. You'll have to include a `history_date` field for the historical table. The below should work:

```
from datetime import datetime
Model = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
HistoricalModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'HistoricalMyModel')

instance = Model.objects.create(name='Test')
HistoricalModel.objects.create(name=instance.name, id=instance.id, history_date=datetime.now())
```